# count the download number of zip file

Tags: javascript, html

I want to count the download number of the zip file in the my web site .
in the html code the link is:

```
<A HREF="http://www.test.com/download/foo.tar.gz">download zip file</A>
```

how to proceed?

Comment: SO isn't a programming service, we expect that questions attempt to solve their problem first and then ask about issues with how they did it.

Comment: it is possible with javascript !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery with Google Analytics to Track Clicks on Outgoing Links From Your Site](http://think2loud.com/105-use-jquery-with-google-analytics-to-track-clicks-on-outgoing-links-from-your-site/)